# show two prices for same product , one for at store and another for ship to home

Tags: magento-1.9, product, pricing

I want to show two prices for same product.
one price will be "ship to home price" and another will be "At store price".
How can i do it and also what changes are required in template to show both.
My website is [www.way2pets.com](http://www.way2pets.com)

Comment: you can create new price attribute in admin panel

Comment: do you want only show the prices at product page or further prices calculation based on (store pickup or shipping price.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to be able to add the product to cart with the "at store" price (for example to pay online and pick up at the store), use a custom option "pickup at store" (type: checkbox, required: no) and set the difference as price for the option. Then you should also implement a shipping method for pickup, though.

If it is just for displaying purposes, create a new attribute "store_price" in `Catalog > Manage Attributes` and select "Is Visible On Product Page"